# Deploying a WCF Service

Tags: web-services, deployment, wcf

I am using WCF for the first time. I Have successfully created the service and it works fine on my local machine. I want to know the steps involved for deploying the service to the client environment (including changes to the config file, IIS settings) and any other miscellaneous settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

There you go - the how to from Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Right click the service project in VS, select Copy Website.
Specify the IIS path. (may need to connect)
Moves / sync all files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also deploy a WCF service to a windows service host. This is desirable in many situations which are outlined here:

[IIS WCF service hosting vs Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560619/iis-wcf-service-hosting-vs-windows-service)