# Choice for WCF Service Hosting with IIS or Self Hosting with Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-ria-services

As we want to develop a new product using Asp.Net MVC 3. The key point here is everything we talk to database by WCF web service.

We are in the phase where we need to decide whether we host WCF web service in IIS OR self hosting with Windows Service.

I raised this question just because I want to know that, what would be the better option to host WCF service that would satisfy my below conditions.

- We're expecting 120 concurrent request / second.  (May be 12,000 request/visit per day)
- Security aspect (Specially WCF Service security)
- Maintainability
- Handling user's concurrent request at the same time (Can Windows Service handle multiple concurrent request comparing to IIS?)

Please do let me know whether I go for IIS hosting OR self hosting with Windows service.

Thanks in advance.

(Could anybody please suggest on this as this is a very crucial part to have decision for further process.)

Comment: If you are able to write a better host than IIS/App Fabric and can do so within a reasonable budget and time box you could write your own Windows Service. In most other cases there is no good reason to imitate IIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1560619/47672

Comment: @0x49D1: I gone through the 'possible duplicate' question before I posted my question here... and logically it's different question than I posted my own here.. I want to know in my 'given context' with WCF hosting!

Comment: *(Can Windows Service handle multiple concurrent request comparing to IIS?)* - **yes of course!** that's what the WCF runtime does for you - whether you're self-hosting, or whether IIS hosts your WCF service - doesn't matter in terms of concurrency

Comment: IIS/AppFabric has worked very for us. I'd use it again over a windows service.

Comment: Out of the conditions listed, I would go with IIS only because install would be easier Id imagine.  All your conditions are cake for WCF regardless if the host is IIS or a WinService

Answer (score 10):

You might interest, This is the "general decision tree" from "**[Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489)**", Juval Lowy.

**Choosing a host for an Internet service:** For an internet application (that is, an application that receives calls from clients across the Internet)

[image: Choosing a host for an Internet service]

**Choosing a host for Intranet service:**
For an intranet application (that is, an application that receives calls from clients within
the same intranet),
[image: Choosing a host for an Intranet service]