# Setting up a WCF host within a website project

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2012

This is going to be a weird question, but:

I'm currently running a wcf service on my website (made in Visual Studio 2012 - .scv file). I have a console client which I try to test the connection with in addition to the built in wcf test client. The test client runs fine and I'm able to call upon the functions, but when I stop running the site/test client (which should mean host by extension, right?), my console client can *still* run and talk to the service just fine.
I'm also able to visit the WCF service page while it's not running in the browser. When I created the WCF in console, I was not able to do any of these things while the host wasn't actually running. Because of this I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the code that I'm just not seeing.

I could see this developing into an issue when I try to get the website online on a server (since my testing client won't be located on the same machine as the service. I'm assuming this is happening because I have access to the files even when it's not running).

What should I do/what is wrong?

Thank you for your time.

relevant web.config code:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
<!-- ICanHasGamez=solution that holds the webpage&wcfservice -->
      <service name="ICanHasGamez.APIHost" behaviorConfiguration="behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ICanHasGamez.IAPIHost">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="behavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

app.config code from the Console Client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAPIHost" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2105/APIHost.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAPIHost" contract="ServiceReference1.IAPIHost"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IAPIHost" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your website project's properties under the web tab, are you hosting it in IIS? If so, the WCF service will keep running, even if you're not using the built in WCF test client. IIS runs on its own, outside of the visual studio environment. You can turn off your service by stopping it in IIS manager, if you'd like, but otherwise it's usable outside of VS.

In contrast, running the WCF service in a console (known as self-hosted) will close down when it's host application, i.e your console application, closes.

In short, if you are using local IIS for your web project, then this isn't anything you've done wrong and is expected behaviour. And regarding running your service on a different machine to your test client, that's not a problem. If you're running it in IIS, then your hosting computer just needs IIS turned on and that project running in IIS there. Voila! If you're running the service as self-hosted, i.e in a console, just leave the console open. Check out [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560619/iis-wcf-service-hosting-vs-windows-service) for some of the pros and cons of self-hosted wcf vs IIS (the accepted answer is a bit local to that particular OP, but the answers below are more informative).

I hope this helps and I hope I'm not barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: I didn't know about this (I'm kinda new to all this programming business). It is checked under "Use Local IIS Web Server". Thanks for clearing this up. You're definitely not barking up the wrong tree, it helped me out a lot. I hope questions like these aren't frowned upon (trying to clear things up contra solving a direct problem) - but it helps me understand how things work. Edit: edited out a question. I'll not bother you with it and try looking it up some more before asking another question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with the scenario you described - its expected behavior.

When you host the WCF service in IIS, as long as IIS is up and running (and there's no other problems), your service can receive requests.  If the service host has been disposed (due to inactivity timeout or other reasons), if a new request is received IIS will spin up a new instance.

On the other hand, if you're self-hosting the WCF service in, for example, a console app, then the only time that service is able to respond to requests is when the self-hosting application is running.

So to answer your question, you're not doing anything wrong, and you don't need to do anything different.  You should be able to simply deploy the WCF Service to the remote server, and then access it with your client.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to explaining the difference between self-host and IIS. Posted a bigger comment in the other answer.