# RESTful WCF hosting

Tags: wcf, rest, iis, hosting

I have a RESTFul WCF service and it needs to be deployed now. I am really confused whether to deploy in windows service or IIS 7. I need to implement SSL also so the protocol would be HTTPS. It is just a simple service consumed by client using HTTPS protocol.
Please let me know which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to have been asked (and answered) previously.

The following link provides a good discussion:
[IIS WCF service hosting vs Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560619/iis-wcf-service-hosting-vs-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

If your RESTFul WCF Service needs to be accessed via http (or https) protocol, then deploy in IIS7.