# WCF service help for new programmer

Tags: .net, wcf, service

I am a beginner with WCF Service and programming world in general, so i need your help to understand and resolve my issue.

I am working in company since 5 months we worked on application using ASP.NET MVC4. I have a task this task required from me to do a WCF Service. I will demonstrate every thing about this WCF service and application to give you full overview.

we have an application this application should connect to views that created by the client ( the application to can work should update some tables that exist in application database from client database for example update employee information) if the application hosted in our server and the views hosted in client server in this case we should use service that connect to views in client server and return the result to our application.

I have a lot of questions on this subject :

1. the query which will select from views should be written by the
   client. how can we do that ?? Does the WCF have UI for example ?
2. what is the most suitable way to host this service ?

I have searched about the subject and found that there is many ways to host the service such as Internet Information Services (IIS)with the new
        Windows Activation Service (WAS) installed with IIS 7.0; or with any
        managed application process including console, Windows Forms,
        Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), or managed Windows service
        applications, And other ways. I don't know what is the most way is
        suitable for our case ?

I am new in this field I have just a very basic knowledge about WCF service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you continue building your knowledge base of WCF, I suggest you consider researching WCF Data Services, which sound like a reasonable design decision given your scenario.

WCF Data Services (formerly known as "ADO.NET Data Services") is a component of the .NET Framework that enables you to create services that use the Open Data Protocol (OData) to expose and consume data over the Web or intranet by using the semantics of representational state transfer (REST). OData exposes data as resources that are addressable by URIs. Data is accessed and changed by using standard HTTP verbs of GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE. OData uses the entity-relationship conventions of the Entity Data Model to expose resources as sets of entities that are related by associations.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792(v=vs.110).aspx

Regarding service hosting, you really have two options for backend data access service hosting: IIS-hosted or Self-hosted.  The following link has a good discussion of the benefits of both.

[IIS WCF service hosting vs Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560619/iis-wcf-service-hosting-vs-windows-service)

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you I will research about WCF Data Service. But I wnat to know Does this technology work on Oracle and SQL database or just SQL??

Comment: WCF Data Services can be used with either SQL Server or Oracle.  The following link shows how to connect to Oracle: http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkWCF/WCFEntityFramework.htm